# ASP NET Core: How to create wwwroot/lib on build

Tags: git, asp.net-core, bower

I have an ASP.NET Core Application and decided not to commit the wwwroot/lib folder with the Bower packages via Git so I included this folder in the .gitignore file.

But after deleting the wwwroot/lib folder I realized that this folder with all the Bower packages is not created automatically on build like for example the NuGet packages.

How do I accomplish that the Bower packages are automatically created/updated etc.?

Comment: Add prepublish scripts do download Bower packages to you project file (project.json or .Csproj)

Comment: Are you using project.Jason or Csproj?

Comment: I am using .csproj

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Project pre-build events approach.

First, make sure you have bower installed on your machine. Command to install:

```
npm install -g bower
```

Command to test if bower is installed run the command below.

```
npm bower -v
```

In pre-build events in your project properties add following command.

```
CD $(MSBuildProjectDirectory)
bower install
```

`CD $(MSBuildProjectDirectory)` was needed to make sure you run `bower install` command in the folder where `bower.json` is located.

Now every time you build your project bower packages will be restored based on `bower.json`.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Does this create all my bower packages as well?